# where can I download IOS DeviceSupport 16A5357B for XCode?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I want to test my app by Iphone7, and IOS version(16A5357B) doesn't support ,where can I find it? [here](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport) is supported version,I want to know where can I download it

Comment: https://hackernoon.com/manually-install-ios-simulators-in-xcode-f7e4bbe50753

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose your package and move it to Xcode's package contents, device support under iPhoneOSPlatform

Try this link

https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport

for the zip files

https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/tree/master/DeviceSupport

Comment: I tested it,but no 16a5457b version. so,I restore IOS to 11.4 and solved it ,that all.Thanx